How to find a closed form for this pattern (if it exists)?
Suppose we have the following code:
Clear["*Global`*"]
A[j_] := A[j] = Range[0, (j!)^2]/((j!)^2)
S2[j_] := 
 S2[j] = Sort[Select[A[j], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 0 &]]
Dist1[j_] := Dist1[j] = Differences[S1[j]]
NonOutliers[j_] := NonOutliers[j] = Dist1[j]
P[j_] := P[j] = NonOutliers[j]/Total[NonOutliers[j]]
entropy[j_] := entropy[j] = Total[-P[j] Log[2, P[j]]]
T[k_]:= T[k] = Table[{j,entropy[j]}, {j, 3, k}]

Question: How do we find a closed form of T as $k\to\infty$?
Attempt: Taking T[k] for k=6 gives us:
{{3,(8 Log[17])/(17 Log[2]) + (9 Log[34])/(17 Log[2])}, 
 {4,(8 Log[287])/(287 Log[2]) + (279 Log[574])/(287 Log[2])}, 
 {5,(224 Log[7199])/(7199 Log[2]) + (6975 Log[14398])/(7199 Log[2])}, 
 {6,(2024 Log[259199])/(259199 Log[2]) + (257175 Log[518398])/(259199 Log[2])}}

From this, I was able to determine:
$$\text{Entropy}[j]=\frac{a(j)\log_{2}(j!^2/2-1)}{j!^2/2-1}+\frac{b(j)\log_{2}(j!^2-2)}{j!^2/2-1}$$
where:
$$\left\{a(3) \mapsto 8,a(4) \mapsto 8,a(5) \mapsto 224,a(6)\mapsto 2024\right\}$$
$$\left\{b(3) \mapsto 9,b(4) \mapsto 279, b(5) \mapsto 6975,b(6) \mapsto 257175\right\}$$
I tried searching for these patterns on OEIS.org but couldn't find anything. I assume since I found a closed form expression for the other terms, we could find a closed expression for these terms.
Am I correct?

Still not sure about finding a closed form but maybe helpful (assuming S1[j] is the same as defined in your previous post ):
S1[j] is just all the numbers n/(j!)^2 in Range[0,(j!)^2]/(j!)^2 s.t. IntegerExponent[n,2] < IntegerExponent[(j!)^2, 2] (since it's the ones with an even denominator, so the denominator has more powers of 2 than the numerator). We also know that IntegerExponent[(j!)^2, 2] is 2 * A011371

Conclusion
We first simplify (this requires knowledge that $a(j) + b(j) = f(j)$, which I show later on)
$$
\mathrm{Entropy[j]} = \frac{a(j) \log _2\left(\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1\right)}{\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1}+\frac{b(j) \log _2\left((j!)^2-2\right)}{\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1}
$$
to
$$
\begin{align}
\text{Entropy}[j] & =\frac{b(j)}{f(j)}+\log _2(f(j)) \\
f(j) & = \frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1
\end{align}
$$
And it looks like you are correct when $b(j)$ is:
$$
b(j) =\frac{1}{2} (j!)^2 \left(1-2^{1-2 \sum _k^{\left\lfloor\log_2 (j)\right\rfloor } \left\lfloor 2^{-k} j\right\rfloor }\right)
$$
for integer $j > 1$. (For $j=1$, you can reproduce entropy[1] by assigning $b(1) = 0$, $f(1) = 1$)

or (in relation to OEIS A000265):
$$
b(j) = -\text{A000265}(2 (f(j)+1))+f(j)+1
$$

or more simply (but with less documentation) in terms of A049606:
$$
b(j) = -\text{A049606}(j)^2+f(j)+1
$$

Also for large $j$, you can use the approximation (this works very well, for $j=6$ the rel. error is already only $3 \times 10^{-4}$ ):
$$
b(j)  \approx 2^{-2 j-1} \left(4^j-8\right) (j!)^2
$$

So as an exact expression of entropy we have:
A049606[j_] := j!/2^IntegerExponent[j!, 2];
f[j_] := (j!)^2/2 - 1
b[j_] := f[j] + 1 - A049606[j]^2;

entropyExact[j_] := Log2[f[j]] + b[j]/f[j]
   


or as a good approximation for entropy:
bApprox[j_] := 2^(-1 - 2 j) (-8 + 4^j) (j!)^2

entropyApprox[j_] := Log2[f[j]] + bApprox[j]/f[j]


And the simplest approximation I can think of, using
$$
f(j) = \frac{(j!)^2}{2} - 1 \approx \frac{(j!)^2}{2}
$$
and the $\frac{b(j)}{f(j)}$ approaches 1 giving
$$
\mathrm{Entropy}[j] = 2 \log _2(j!)
$$
entropyVeryApprox[j_] := 2 Log2[j!]


My walk through of how I did this is below, and I found my own expression for entropy (it works for integer j>1) but it is quite messy so I probably will try to come back at some point to make this easier to understand
Walkthrough
I first assume you are still using this definition of S1[j].
Let's start with just this part:
A[j_] := A[j] = Range[0, (j!)^2]/((j!)^2)
S1[j_] := 
 S1[j] = Sort[Select[A[j], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 1 &]]
S2[j_] := 
 S2[j] = Sort[Select[A[j], Boole[IntegerQ[Denominator[#]/2]] == 0 &]]

Observe that S2[j] is all the fractions n/(j!)^2 with n in Range[0, (j!)^2] with odd denominators. This means that n has at least as many powers of 2 in its factorization as (j!)^2 has. In other words S2[j] is all the n/(j!)^2 such that
IntegerExponent[n, 2] >= IntegerExponent[(j!)^2, 2]

IntegerExponent[j!,2] is given by A011371 in OEIS, and IntegerExponent[(j!)^2, 2] = 2*A011371. We can use one of the formulas from A011371 to get an expression for IntegerExponent[(j!)^2, 2] (I call it intExp here) as a sum:
intExp[j_] := 2 Sum[Floor[j/2^k], {k, Floor@Log2@j}]


Also observe when j is large (and so Floor only introduces tiny error), $\mathrm{intExp}(j) \approx 2 \sum _k^{\log _2(j)} \frac{j}{2^k} = 2(-1 + j)$ (this will be important later):
Plot[{intExp[n], 2 (-1 + n), IntegerExponent[(Floor[n]!)^2, 2]}, {n, 1, 
  500}, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"n", IntegerExponent[(n!)^2, 2] }]


The length of S2[j] is now just the number of n with IntegerExponent[n,2] ≥ intExp[j] which is $\frac{(j!)^2}{2^{intExp(j)}}+1$ (plus 1 because of the endpoint):
s2Len[j_] := 1 + (j!)^2/2^intExp[j]

And we can quickly confirm this:
Table[Length@S2[j] == s2Len[j], {j, 6}]
(*{True, True, True, True, True, True}*)


Let's now look at the next step in defining entropy:
Dist1[j_] := Dist1[j] = Differences[S1[j]]

The Differences of S1[j] will consist of only two unique values (since S2[j] can only exist on even numbers, so there will never be 2 elements of S2[j] next to each other in A[j]): 1/(j!)^2 when there is no element of S2[j] to skip over, and 2/(j!)^2 when it has to skip over an element of S2[j].
We already know the length of S1[j] is (j!)^2 - s2Len[j], and of those elements, s2Len[j]-2 (minus 2 because of endpoints) will be of difference size 2/(j!)^2, while the others will be of difference size 1/(j!)^2. So we can define the lengths of each difference size:
s1LenDiff1[j_] := 2 - 2 s2Len[j] + (j!)^2
s1LenDiff2[j_] := s2Len[j] - 2

And we can again confirm this reproduces Dist1 (I have to throw out the cases for when j ≤ 2 when s1LenDiff2 produces a length ≤ 0, but it works for j>2):
compareForTally[j_] := 
 Select[{{1/(j!)^2, s1LenDiff1[j]}, {2/(j!)^2, 
    s1LenDiff2[j]}}, #[[2]] > 0 &]

Table[Tally@Dist1[j] == compareForTally[j], {j, 6}]

(* {True, True, True, True, True, True} *)


Also note that your $a$ sequence equals s1LenDiff2[j, while your $b$ sequence is s1LenDiff1[j]/2:
a[j_] := s1LenDiff2[j];
b[j_] := s1LenDiff1[j]/2;
Table[{a[j], b[j]}, {j, 3, 6}]
(*{{8, 9}, {8, 279}, {224, 6975}, {2024, 257175}}*)


And note $a(j) + b(j) = f(j)$ (this is how I simplified your expression at the very beginning of my answer):
Simplify[a[j] + b[j] == f[j]]
(*True*)


Now we arrive at the definition of P, which is just the differences of S1 normalized by total:
P[j_] := P[j] = NonOutliers[j]/Total[NonOutliers[j]]

Since P is linearly related to Diff, it still just consists of two unique values pStepSize and 2pStepSize. With some algebra it is possible to show that for j > 2
pStepSize[j_] := 1/(s1LenDiff1[j] + 2 s1LenDiff2[j])

Again of course I will confirm this:
Table[DeleteDuplicates[P[j]] == {1, 2}*pStepSize[j], {j, 3, 6}]

(*{True, True, True, True}*)



And finally we arrive at the definition of entropy:
entropy[j_] := entropy[j] = Total[-P[j] Log[2, P[j]]]

But since P just consists of 2 things we have already calculate, we can write this as:
ENT[j_] := 
 Table[-k*pStepSize[j]*Log2[k*pStepSize[j]], {k, 2}] . {s1LenDiff1[j],
    s1LenDiff2[j]}

And confirm once again for j>2:
Table[entropy[j] == ENT[j], {j, 3, 6}]

(*{True, True, True, True}*)



Finding the limit of entropy[j] for large j
We now use $\mathrm{intExp}(j) \approx 2(-1 + j)$ to get an expression for entropy[j] (I call it lim[j]) as j goes to infinity. I also calculate your function in the large j limit arbujaLIM:
ClearAll[intExp]
intExp[j_] = 2 (-1 + j);


s2Len[j_] := 1 + (j!)^2/2^intExp[j]
s1LenDiff1[j_] := 2 - 2 s2Len[j] + (j!)^2
s1LenDiff2[j_] := s2Len[j] - 2

pStepSize[j_] := 1/(s1LenDiff1[j] + 2 s1LenDiff2[j])

entLIM[j_] = 
  Table[-k*pStepSize[j]*Log2[k*pStepSize[j]], {k, 2}] . {s1LenDiff1[
     j], s1LenDiff2[j]};

entLIM[j_] = FullSimplify[entLIM[j], j \[Element] PositiveIntegers];

lim[j_] = 
 FullSimplify[
  PowerExpand[Series[entLIM[j], {j, Infinity, 1}] // Normal], 
  j \[Element] PositiveIntegers]
(*
(8 (9 E^(2 j) j - 4^-j j^(2 j) (1 + 12 j (1 + 6 j)) \[Pi]))/(-72 E^(
   2 j) j + j^(2 j) (1 + 12 j (1 + 6 j)) \[Pi]) + 
 Log[-2 + 1/36 E^(2 j (-1 + Log[j])) (12 + 1/j + 72 j) \[Pi]]/Log[2]
*)

a[j_] := s1LenDiff2[j];
b[j_] := 1/2 * s1LenDiff1[j];
arbujaLIM[j_] = (a[j] Log2[(j!)^2/2 - 1])/((j!)^2/2 - 1) + (
  b[j] Log2[(j!)^2 - 2])/((j!)^2/2 - 1);


So we have 2 approximations
$$
\mathrm{lim}(j) = \frac{8 \left(9 e^{2 j} j-\pi  4^{-j} j^{2 j} (12 j (6 j+1)+1)\right)}{\pi  j^{2 j} (12 j (6 j+1)+1)-72 e^{2 j} j}+\frac{\log \left(\frac{1}{36} \pi  \left(72 j+\frac{1}{j}+12\right) e^{2 j (\log (j)-1)}-2\right)}{\log (2)}
$$
and
$$
\begin{align}
\text{arbujaLIM}(j) & =\frac{a(j) \log _2\left(\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1\right)}{\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1}+\frac{b(j) \log _2\left((j!)^2-2\right)}{\frac{(j!)^2}{2}-1}\\
 a(j) & = 4^{1-j} (j!)^2-1 \\
b(j) & = 2^{-2 j-1} \left(4^j-8\right) (j!)^2
\end{align}
$$

Comparing my approximation lim to the exact value of entropy, and your function for entropy as well (I call it arbujaEXACT):
intExp[n_] := 2 Sum[Floor[n/2^k], {k, Floor@Log2@n}]
entEXACT[j_] = 
  Table[-k*pStepSize[j]*Log2[k*pStepSize[j]], {k, 2}] . {s1LenDiff1[
     j], s1LenDiff2[j]};

entEXACT[j_] = FullSimplify[entEXACT[j], j \[Element] PositiveIntegers]

a[j_] := s1LenDiff2[j];
b[j_] := 1/2 * s1LenDiff1[j];
arbujaEXACT[j_] = (a[j] Log2[(j!)^2/2 - 1])/((j!)^2/2 - 1) + (
  b[j] Log2[(j!)^2 - 2])/((j!)^2/2 - 1);


$$
\mathrm{entEXACT(j)} = \frac{(j!)^2 \left(\log (4) \left(-4^{-\sum _k^{\left\lfloor \frac{\log (j)}{\log (2)}\right\rfloor } \left\lfloor 2^{-k} j\right\rfloor }\right)-\log \left(\frac{1}{(j!)^2-2}\right)\right)+2 \log \left(\frac{2}{(j!)^2-2}\right)}{\log (2) \left((j!)^2-2\right)}
$$

And plot together, along with rel. abs. error:
DiscretePlot[{entEXACT[j], lim[j]}, {j, 2, 100}, Joined -> True, 
 Filling -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", Frame -> True, 
 FrameLabel -> {"j", "entropy(j)"}, 
 LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]




In the error plot, we see your expression with the approximate $a(j), b(j)$ is much better than my approximation
 errPlot = 
 DiscretePlot[{Abs[(arbujaEXACT[j] - lim[j])/arbujaEXACT[j]], 
   Abs[(arbujaEXACT[j] - arbujaLIM[j])/arbujaEXACT[j]]}, {j, 2, 100}, 
  Joined -> True, Filling -> None, PlotLegends -> "Expressions", 
  ScalingFunctions -> "Log", PlotRange -> All, Frame -> True, 
  FrameLabel -> {"j", "rel. abs. error"}, 
  LabelStyle -> Directive[Bold, Medium]]




And finally note all three exact expressions for entropy are equal for j>1 (you can also get the j=1 case to work if you force s1LenDiff1 to be 0 instead of -1/2 when j=1:
Quiet[Table[
  FullSimplify[entEXACT[j] == arbujaEXACT[j] == entropy[j]], {j, 2, 
   6}]]

(*{True, True, True, True, True}*)



I suspected the simplest approximation would $2\log_2(x!)$. Thank you, for checking.

Hence, if A[j_] := A[j] = Range[0, (j!)]/((j!)), the simplest approximation would be $\log_{2}(x!)$

When you have time, could you try to answer this question?
